# Rails - How do I write this string condition as an array condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

```
named_scope :correct, :include => :correction, :conditions => "checked_at IS NOT NULL AND corrections.id IS NULL"
```

On a side note I have googled loads and looked through books but i cant seem to find a list of all the various types of conditions you can use and how they differ when implenting them as strings, arrays or hashes.

Is there a list of the syntax anywhere?

Comment: Why do you want to use the array format if there's no variable aspect of the condition?

Comment: it was just for examples sake really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you posted is correct. Also, there's no way to express the same condition using arrays or hashes.

Array–syntax and Hash-syntax are useful when you need to interpolate values. For instance, the following condition

```
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => "field = '1'"
```

can be written as

```
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => ["field = ?", "1"]
```

or

```
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => { :field => "1" }
```

The Hash-syntax is a subset of the Array-syntax and supports only a limited set of operators.
For instance, you can transform

```
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => ["field1 = ? AND field2 IN (?)", "1", ["foo", "bar"]]
```

into

```
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => { :field1 => "1", :field2 => ["foo", "bar"] }
```

but there's no Hash-equivalent for

```
# OR
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => ["field1 = ? OR field2 IN (?)", "1", ["foo", "bar"]]
# <>
named_scope :is_one, :conditions => ["field1 <> ?", "1"]
```

Comment: thank you very much simone for explaining that. Thats really helped me a lot!